# How to create IDbConnection factory using Autofac for Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, dapper

In my project I'm using Autofac and Dapper, and so far I've been registering required `IDbConnection` in that way:

```
builder
    .Register<IDbConnection>(c => new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But now I'm facing the problem that with that implementation I cannot make parallel operations on database.

Solution for that is to creates a factory I suppose. But I cannot find any information how it can be achived using Autofac.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Instance Scope information for Autofac? I'm not sure about your case, but have you considered using the scope, `InstancePerDependency`? [Autofac - Instance Scope](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html). The document states, _"Also called ‘transient’ or ‘factory’ in other containers. Using per-dependency scope, a unique instance will be returned from each request for a service."_.

Comment: I think it won't work. Let's say you're injecting IDbConnection in `MyDapperService`.
Then you're injecting your `MyDapperService` in your `MyQueryClass` if you will call `MyDapperService.CallDatabaseMethod` multiple times it will be still the same instance, because you've injected it once in `MyQueryClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've solved this. Let me know if you see something that might be improved.

```
builder.Register(ctx => new DbConnectionFactory(_connectionString))
    .Named<DbConnectionFactory>(nameof(DbConnectionFactory))
    .InstancePerDependency();

builder.Register<Func<DbConnectionFactory>>(c =>
{
    var cc = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
    return () => cc.ResolveNamed<DbConnectionFactory>(nameof(DbConnectionFactory));
});
```

Factory:

```
public class DbConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbConnectionFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
}
```

Usage in any class by injection `Func<DbConnectionFactory> dbConnectionFactory` and calling:

```
using (var connection = _dbConnectionFactory().Connection)
{
    var result = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(Query, Parameters);
    return result.ToList();
}
```